# How can I convert this to be an extension of the Array Prototype?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanneufeld/Y8ZNU/

With this example I have created a queue modeled after how I assume google is handling analytics events. The thing is I'd like to convert it to be an extension of the array prototype.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when you create a new instance of Queue and pass in a queue array, the new instance would act as an array with the extra functions I've added.

Comment: [It's not quite possible to make your own subclass of Array in JavaScript](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function log() {
    /* workaround for chrome not playing nice and letting me .apply to console */
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}

var q = q || [[log, 'first item q1']],
    q2 = q2 || [[log, 'first time q2']];

// You'll want a console open for this.

function Queue(_q, name) {
    var _q = _q || [],
        name = name || 'mlQueue';

    function processQueue() {
        task = _q.shift();
        while (task) {
            func = task.shift();
            func.apply(window, task);
            task = _q.shift();
            }
        }

        function init() {
            _q._push = _q.push;
            processQueue();
            _q.push = function() {
            //first push it to the array
            _q._push.apply(_q, arguments);
            processQueue();
        };
    }

    function push() {
        console.log(name + ' pushing values');
        _q.push.apply(_q, arguments);
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        push: push,
        run: processQueue,
        name: name
    }
};

var q = new Queue(q, 'q1');
q.push([log, 'q1 and more']);
q.init();
q.push([log, 'q1 and more']);

var q2 = new Queue(q2, 'q2');
q2.init();
q2.push([log, 'q2 and more']);​
```

Answer (score 1):

**might not be perfect but it get the job done: (see the link provided by @Pointy in the comments for a good explanation as to what the pitfalls are)**

```
function pseudoArray(name) {

  if (!(this instanceof pseudoArray)) {
      return new pseudoArray(name);
  }

  var self = this;

  self.name = name || 'defaultName';

  var _push = self.push;
  self.push = function(args) {
      console.log('"' + name + '" pushing [ ' + Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments) + ' ]');
      _push.apply(self, arguments);
  };

  return self;

}

pseudoArray.prototype = [];

var x = new pseudoArray('fake array');

x.push('yay', 77, function() { alert('yup'); });
x.push('things');
x.push(12);

console.log(x instanceof Array);
console.log('to string: ' + x);
console.log('length: ' + x.length);
console.log('pop result: ' + x.pop());
console.log('length: ' + x.length);
```

Comment: I came up with this for a solution in the end:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanneufeld/Y8ZNU/10/